# Why Graphicsmagic produces thumbnails much larger in file size that Imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

`input.jpg` is 3264×2448 px, 1.78 MB.

I have created two thumbnails with identical arguments, in imagemagick 7.0.8-11:

```
convert input.jpg -quality 50 -thumbnail 200x200 thumb_im.jpg
```

and graphicsmagick 1.3.30:

```
gm convert input.jpg -quality 50 -thumbnail 200x200 thumb_gm.jpg
```

The results are: imagemagick — 4.31 kB, graphicsmagick — 27.8 kB. Visually these images are similar in quality but not identical.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try putting -quality 50 after creating the thumbnail just before the output. If no change, then note that GraphicsMagick was a early offshoot of ImageMagick and has not changed much since. ImageMagick has gone through lots of changes, enhancements and improvements and so may be more optimized than GraphicsMagick. With ImageMagick 7, you should be using magick rather than convert otherwise, you are likely accessing ImageMagick 6 rather than 7, unless you have a symbolic link set up between convert and magick.  Different q-table and and different measures of -quality are possible, also.

Comment: Yes I actually tried putting `-quality` just before the output then moved it where it is now, there is no difference. Also "`convert -quality`" returns version 7.

Comment: Is there some  extra metadata in there? Perhaps GM is copying over an IPCT chunk that IM is stripping? You'd need to post your source image and the two thumbnails.

Comment: Did you mean `convert -version` not `convert -quality`? Even so, it may report IM 7, but really be using IM 6 legacy code.